# mysql and php function not displaying % percentage sign correctly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to build a web application.

This app has a autoconfiguration Network interface for Multicast, which generates the non valid IP multicast based on card information. In the app.txt conf file I input the following data

```
auto_ip4=239.106.%card.%number
```

it scans the card number and on the log outputs the IP multicast like this example 239.105.2.1 and this works correctly, but on the frontend webgui things go wrong.

We have a function that saves the input data and stores it on a mysql db; the mysql table records 3 values   ID, NAME, VALUE

The value function is where the data gets store 239.105.%card.%number

When i press save the recorded looks like this: `239.105.?rd.%number` and when i export it the text configuration file looks like this

```
auto_ip4=239.106.?rd.%number
```

This is the PHP form code that saves data value into the mysql database

```
<?=form_open('config/edit/'.$config->id.'/valid')?>
<table class="form">
    <tr>
        <th>Config param</th>
        <td><?=$config->name?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="value" value="<?=$config->value?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?=form_close()?>
```

Aparently this only happens on the first % sign, the second one gets stored correctly.

Comment: Hi it seems its somehow related to hexadecimal characters, i have tested input .%ca  cb cc cd ce cf   and allways replaces this to ?

Comment: but if i input 239.106.%cord.%number   the input text gets stored correctly..

Comment: The PHP code in your question *displays* the form, but isn't the code that *saves* it. Edit your question to show that code.

Comment: You seem to be doing something on save that's messing it up, so that code is likely the source of the problem. This is just standard view code.

Comment: When you send the data to the server, is it as a GET or a PUT? Be sure to URLEncode your data if it's sent as a GET.

Comment: The code you have shown us does not interact with a MySQL database. You also seem to be describing 2 seperate files.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that `239.105.%card.%number` becomes `239.105.?rd.%number`, and that you specified in the comments that you get the text correctly using `239.106.%cord.%number`

**There's no doubt that the problem occurs because you mess up somewhere with the `urldecode()` function.**

Check this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

% act as the beginning of a char to encode in url encoding.

**%CA** is decoded to **Ê**

Your string `239.105.%card.%number` has in fact become `239.106.Êrd.%number`

You see a `?` either because your output app can't display Ê, or because the character-set of your database/table doesn't manage that specific special character. If you were for instance on utf-8, utf-16 or any latin-based charset, on both sides, you would see the Ê

All the rest shown in your examples that works :

- `%nu` in %number
- `%co` in %cord

are not valid url encoding characters, thus they are stored as plain text and/or not decoded. It is the reason for this weird behavior.

It's hard to tell you exactly how to fix the problem without seeing your code.

Comment: Hi yes i am most shure, this is some sort of charset.. because this is exactly what is happening, i am using codeigniter, i will try to get more information on how to stop this from happening, as i need this to be stored in plain text instead of enconding character.

Comment: so how can i stop codeigniter from picking this plain text  %card  and avoid from converting it to ?rd which results on 239.106.?rd.%number   instead of beeing copiead as plain text data 239.106.%card.%number

Answer (score 0):

this is some sort of charset..   my charset on codeigniter app is set to UTF-8
config.php
PHP Code:
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

database.php
PHP Code:
$db['default']['char_set'] = "iso-8859-1"; // or latin1
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "latin1_general_ci"; // or latin1_swedish_ci

and on my db mysql i have tried setting the same but something is still giving me issues..  because the data input  %card   it gets stored on the db as ?rd,  interesting this just happens on the write function of the copied data to the mysql DB, if i login via phpmyadmin to the database and input the data correctly on the value  %card,  then i refresh the config page php that i use to input the data to read data back from the database, the data displays correctly as %card, but when i try to write back to the db it encodes it wrong and saves it on the db as ?rd

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**

 */

class Config_model extends Model {
    var $id;
    var $name;
    var $value;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::Model();
    }

    public function findAll() {
        $query = $this->db->get('config');
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function find($id) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('config', array('id' => $id));
        return $query->row();
    }

    public function findOneByName($name) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('config', array('name' => $name));
        return $query->row();
    }

    public function countAll() {
        $query = $this->db->get('config');
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function add($data) {
        $this->db->insert('config', $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function delete($id) {
        if ($this->db->delete('config', array('id' => $id))) return true;
    }

    public function update($id, $data) {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('config', $data);
    }
}
```